# async return promise in a settimeout function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

```js
const name = async() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return Promise.resolve("1")
  }, 1000);
};

(async function() {
  console.log("hello2");
})();

const timer = async() => {
  console.log(await name());
  console.log("hello4");
};
timer()
```

expected output:

```
hello2
1
hello4
```

output is:

```
hello2 
undefined
hello4
```

If i removed the settimeout function and return a promise alobe like this

```
const name = async () => {
    return Promise.resolve("1")
};
```

function is returning 1 and it is getting resolved, what is the issue with when i am returning with settimeout function

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62381734/edit) instead of re-posting it.

Comment: @Bergi i am not understanding it , can you explain this how  works. i have edited my previous question too.